# How can I run the same code for a custom exception and a standard exception?

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

I have a custom exception class that extends Exception and adds on the ability to pass back more data on what threw the exception. The problem now is if I want to catch my custom exception and a standard exception, but handle them with the same block of code, I don't know how to do that other than create a new function (which I don't want to do for every place I'd like to use this).

```
try {

} catch(QM\DebugInfoException $e) {
    // I don't want to duplicate the Exception handling code up here
}catch(Exception $e){
    $db->rollBack();

    $return['error'] = 1;
    $return['errInfo'] = array(
        'code' => $e->getCode(),
        'message' => $e->getMessage(),
        'trace' => $e->getTraceAsString()
    );

    // I'd rather handle both here, and just add data on to $return['errInfo']
    switch ($ExceptionType) {
        case 'QM\DebugInfoException':
            $return['errInfo']['extraInfo'] = $e->getExtraInfo();
            break;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any good ideas on this?

Comment: Try using 'throw' in the upper exception handling code. It will 'throw the exception on'.

Comment: You can remove first block completely. Just use catch(Exception $ex). It will catch both. Use use a function Handler and pass the Exception as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a get_class($e) and that will return the string representing the class name of the exception object then use that to compare in your switch.

Another option is to put a function that encapsulates the common functionality, and call it from each of the exception blocks.  That way new, unexpected exceptions not in your switch can still percolate up.  I'm a big fan of explicitly catching specific exceptions.

Comment: Solution I used was: if (get_class($e) == 'QM\DebugInfoException') {$return['errInfo']['extraInfo'] = $e->getExtraInfo();}